# How to send and recieve responses from one server to another server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request

I want to send an ajax request to a server where my db connections and other things works. What I want is to send 2 post values through ajax to that server and that server will give a response back. See example code below.

```
post_data = {'userName':name, 'userPass':password};
$.post('http://www.example2.com/script.php', post_data, function(response){
//doing something with response
}
```

This code is in example1.com and we are sending post data to example2.com. But when I try this I get an error that is given below.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.example2.com/script.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS
```

So I have to enable something. I have no idea how to enable CORS. How to do that?

Comment: Read about JSONP. Or you can use curl in your php script, just call it with ajax.

Comment: For testing just put `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` at the start of your PHP script. Do **not** put this into production before learning about what it really does.

Comment: This helped. But may I know the security issue if I use this?